# Category page Grid - Manual/Custom Product Sequence on Page Load (Store View level)

Tags: magento2, magento-community

Is it possible to manually set the sequence of product items that appear for a specific category on page load for different Store Views

However, when filters are applied by Visitor, then sequence changes accordingly.

```
community-edition magento2
```

Comment: Its not possible  for different Store Views manually set  sequence of product items that appear for a specific category on page load. You have to create extension for it.

Comment: @ChiragParmar Would you recommend any link on how I can get it to work on 2,3?

Comment: I did not found exactly reference for your requirement.